# Spacing Out API Calls in Promise.allSettled

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api

I have purchased access to an API that has a set limit of 5 calls per second.  I have a list of end-points that I want to hit for that API and am using the following code to loop through those end-points and fetch the data I need:

```
  async function getData(endpoints) {
    const promised = await Promise.allSettled(
      endpoints.map(async (endpoint) => {
        const response = await fetch(`${urlStart}/${endpoint}/${urlEnd}`);
        const data = await response.json();

        const results = {
          endpoint,
          data,
        };

        return results;
      })
    );

    return promised;
```

Now, this kind of works -- however, I am getting a lot of rejections with the following error message:

```
{
  "name": "ConnectTimeoutError",
  "code": "UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT",
  "message": "Connect Timeout Error"
}
```

My suspicion is that I am hitting the API too many times per second and that is why I am getting these rejections.

As such, I am wondering how I can modify my code so that I space out the fetch calls so that I run one call every 200 milliseconds (i.e., 5 times per second).

I experimented with setTimeout and setInterval, but couldn't really figure out how to make it work.  At best, it did nothing -- at worse it returned less results.

So, I am wondering, how can I space out my fetch calls within Promise.allSettled?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not the `Promise.allSettled` that can do anything about this. It's `endpoints.map()` that needs to be spaced out.

Comment: Indeed, I put the `setTimeout` or `setInterval` inside of `endpoints.map()`, but still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: So you intend to make subsequent requests with ~200ms apart and what do you want to happen if a later made one resolves before a previous one?